# Android: how to draw bitmap behind some path?

Tags: android

The task is following:

To draw parts of some bitmap only behind a path (user draws path using his finger). It must look like the user draws this bitmap by his finger. It is similar to task: erasing some picture by finger, but the approach should be different.

I know it is possible with OpenGL, but at first i am looking for more light option with standard android canvas and view drawing.

I have seen the example FingerPaint in APIDemos (please, do not refer me to it).

I am interested in somebody's real experience of implementing this task, or any other info, links or code, which can help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say to *not* refer you to FingerPaint, but have you considered that this sample may indeed hold the answer?

You could adapt it to two views on top of each other... your hidden image underneath and the fingerpaint view acting as a mask on top. You "paint" with the colour 0x00000000, i.e. total transparency, thereby revealing the image in the view underneath.

Comment: hi, Reuben, thanks for answer.. Sorry, my bad - i didn't clarify the task more precisely.. I have a separate background (play area) above which i should draw these parts of another image, so i can not use your method cause in this case my background won't be visible..

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you have *two* bitmaps, and that 'painting' reveals the second one?

Comment: If 'yes' to that, then just do the fingerpaint with a BitmapShader hooked to your 2nd bitmap, rather than a solid color.